# Telegram-cli как обрабатывать запросы через php?

Tags: telegram

Делаю бота через telegram-cli.
Установил telegram-cli на сервер, все хорошо работает.

Чтобы бот автоматически отвечал, делаю так: `bin/telegram-cli -k tg-server.pub -W -s query.lua`
Запросы к боту идут на файл `query.lua`.

**Вот как сделать так, чтоб запросы сделанные боту отправлялись на PHP файл и обрабатывались им?**

Смотрел вот сюда https://github.com/zyberspace/php-telegram-cli-client, но ничего так и не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

*У меня скорей не ответ на вопрос, а вопрос на вопрос*:

Зачем для создания бота вы используете `telegram-cli`, если уже некоторое время назад у Telegram реализован [API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) именно для ботов? Там есть [примеры](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples#php) и на PHP, кстати.

Тем более, автор репозитория **php-telegram-cli-client**, который вы используете, намекает на это:

> As i currently have no time to work on this project anymore and **telegram released its own bot-api**, there won't be many new updates to this project in the future

А также советует переехать на **[unofficial php-sdk](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk)**:

> If you want to port your project to the new bot-api take a look at the **unofficial php-sdk**.

Comment: Да, я все понимаю. У меня огромное количество ботов созданных именно на API для ботов. Но появилась большая необходимость создать бота именно на telegram-cli, без окончания на bot и именно как обычный аккаунт. Если вы знаете как, пожалуйста помогите :)

Comment: @Ramzan поздновато увидел, но пока что `telegram-cli` умеет работать только с python и lua, напишите на них